# jquery fucntion doesn't fire controller on page refresh after ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

my script executes well on page load. call every function and sets values to every textbox.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setPageValues();

 $("#btnSavechanges").click(function () {
  //ajax call to update database.
 });
  
});

 var setPageValues = function(){
     //Ajax Call to controller and set text box value on page
 }
```

After save changes. it updates values on database successfully but on page refresh(setPageValues() doesn't call updated ones) it shows previous value and not the saved ones.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Disabling cache of your ajax call may resolve the issue..

Comment: Does `$("#btnSavechanges").click` refreshes the page? You have told  that `updates values on database successfully but on page refresh`, if that is through `ajax` it should not refresh the page? OR are you saying that, after click, you have manually refreshed the page to see changes?

Comment: @ArindamNayak  ajax doesn't refresh page. I am using F5 ot ctrl+F5 or page navigation.

Comment: @WebArtifice Thanks.. works as a charm.. :)

Comment: Got it, i have a suggestion. In JS generate a random number, append that to ajax URL , this way browser will know that each request to URL is different and it will not cache the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try adding the following javascripts: 



<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```

Comment: These files are already there.. @WebArtifice comment solved my problem.